# What regex for jQuery satisfies these conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have a field for which can have:

- Up to potentially 2 decimals places
- Up to potentially 6 non-decimal places
- No more than 8 digits altogether (the max 2 decimals plus max 6 non-decimals)
- Be a positive number

So correct inputs would be range from 0.01 to 999999.99, and trailing zeroes isn't an issue, so 4.00 is just as fine as 4.

Comment: FWIW, regular expressions have nothing to do with jQuery. What have you tried so far?

Comment: SO isn't a code factory, where you can just order code for free. You need to show that you've actually spent some time figuring things out yourself by posting at least a rudimentary attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't word that greatly, I was just making it clear that I was looking for a Javascript solution :) So far I've tried attempting this via Django through an API then using inbuilt validation. This was a complete failure, and also relied on using an API call just to validate an input field which was silly on my part. I was hoping Regex would be my salvation. but I'm a regex eejit :)



@t0mppa My apologies. I've seen dozens of other questions providing Regex solutions without providing existing attempts, so I thought I could follow suit. I'll be more careful in the future :)

Comment: You can't have up to 2 decimal places and have an integer range requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^[0-9]{1,6}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2}0*)?$
```

If you want to allow leading and trailing whitespace, add `\s*` to the beginning and the end of the pattern, right after `^` and right before `$`.

That said, this task is something you might want to accomplish without regex. Why don't you just read the value of the input, parse it and then simply perform a numeric validation? You could even round the input to two decimal places.

Comment: This allows leading zeros though.

Comment: @FelixKling Why shouldn't it? 0.01 is a perfectly valid number.

Comment: Yes, but I mean `00042` for example. I'm not saying that this can't be accounted for, it just might be worth to point out (since the OP explicitly said *"trailing zeroes isn't an issue"*, but nothing about leading zeros).

Comment: @FelixKling … which also is a perfectly fine number. ;) You could modify the beginning of the pattern accordingly, though: `(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,5})`

Comment: My fault in any case, I didn't specify whether it should or shouldn't. Thanks for your help, it seems to work :)

Comment: @Geesh_SO If my answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like so:

- Up to potentially 2 decimals places: `(\.\d{1,2})?` - This will match a decimal point followed by a minimum of 1, and a maximum of 2 digits. This is optional.
- Up to potentially 6 non-decimal places: `\d{1,6}` - This will match a minimum of 1 digit and a maximum of 6 digits.
- No more than 8 digits altogether (the max 2 decimals plus max 6 non-decimals): You can combing the two above to get this: `\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?`.
- Be a positive number: Change the above to this: `^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$`. This should make sure that any number you pass to it, does not start with a negative sign. The `^` and `$` anchors instruct the regex engine to start matching at the beginning of the string and complete the matching at the end. This should allow you to be sure that the string you are matching is indeed a number.

That being said, you should really be doing numerical range checks using the appropriate mathematical operations which your language (in this case JavaScript) provides. A small change in the numerical range you are after will most likely bring a large change in your regular expression.

Comment: I was trying to look for that but regex always seemed to show up. Possibly my Google-foo is quite bad. I'll try to research more options, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This might validate it

```
 #  /^(?=.*[1-9].*$)(?=[.]?(?:\d[.]?){1,8}$)(?=\d{0,6}(?:[.]\d{0,2})?$)/

 ^ 
 (?=                      # must be a positive number
      .* [1-9] .* $ 
 )
 (?=
      [.]? 
      (?:                 # 1 to 8 digits
           \d 
           [.]? 
      ){1,8}
      $ 
 )
 (?=
      \d{0,6}             # 0 to 6 non-decimal places
      (?:
           [.]            # 0 to 2 decimal places
           \d{0,2} 
      )?
      $ 
 )
```